# A limit involving polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, limits

Let be the polynomial:

$$P_n (x)=x^{n+1} - (x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x+1)$$

I want to prove that it has a single positive real root we'll denote by $x_n$, and then to compute:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n}$$

Comment: Numerically the root converges to $\phi = \dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}2$.

Comment: @Marvis: very interesting. This is the golden number.

Comment: Really? if you evaluate the expression at $\phi$, you get $2/(\sqrt 5-1)$. Kind of funny.

Comment: By summing the geometric series, we see that $P_n(x) = 0$ iff $x^n (x^2-x-1) = -1$, so if $x>1$ and $n$ is large, then $x^2-x-1$ has to be very small, which explains why $\phi$ appears.

Comment: @HansLundmark There's an additional root at $x = 1$ that you get that way : $x^n(x^2 - x - 1) + 1 = (x-1)P_n(x)$

Comment: @Cocopuffs: Ah yes, that's true, so "iff" was a bit sloppy there. But the point wasn't the root $x=1$, but the root $x \approx \phi$. :-)

Comment: To prove it has a single positive root, you can use Descartes' Rule of Signs.

Comment: Thanks for all your solutions / suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's not much more work, let's study the roots in $\mathbb{C}$.

Note that $x=1$ is not a solution unless $n=1$, since $P_n(1) = 1-n$.

Since we are interested in the limit $n\to\infty$, we can assume $x\ne 1$.
Sum the geometric series,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
P_n (x) &=& x^{n+1} - (x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x+1) \\
&=& x^{n+1} - \frac{x^n-1}{x-1}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
The roots will satisfy
$$x_n^{n}(x_n^2-x_n-1) = -1.$$

(*Addendum*: If there are concerns about convergence of the sum, think of summing the series as a shorthand that reminds us that $(x-1)P_n(x) = x^{n}(x^2-x-1) + 1$ for all $x$.)

If $0\le |x_n|<1$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} x^n = 0$, thus, in the limit, there are no complex roots in the interior of the unit circle.

If $|x_n|>1$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1/x^n = 0$, thus, in the limit, the roots must satisfy 
$$x_n^2 - x_n - 1 = 0.$$
There is one solution to this quadratic equation with $|x_n|>1$, it is real and positive, 
$$x_n = \frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{5}).$$
This is the golden ratio. 
It is the only root exterior to the unit circle.

The rest of the roots must lie on the boundary of the unit circle.

[image: Contour plot of $|P_{15}(x+i y)|$.]

Figure 1. Contour plot of $|P_{15}(x+i y)|$.

Comment: interesting approach and nice graph. :-)

Comment: Another interesting question!

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT: This is an answer I wrote a long time ago, which I don't think is especially clear. Please read @GenericHuman's answer below for a better treatment.**

$$P_n(x)=x^{n+1}-(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+...x+1)=x^{n+1}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{k}$$
By the formula for the sum of a finite geometric series, we have, if x $\ne$ 1:
$$P_n(x)=x^{n+1}-\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$$
Equating to zero,
$$x^{n+1}=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1} \implies x^{n+1}(x-1)=x^{n+2}-x^{n+1}=x^n-1 \implies x^{n+2}-x^{n+1}-x^{n}=-1$$
So, provided x $\ne$ 0, we also have $x^2-x-1=\frac{-1}{x^n}$
Now we can limit both sides as n approaches infinity, to get (assuming x>1) $$x^2-x-1=0 \implies x=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Let us establish the uniqueness of this root for x>1:
$$P_n'(x)=(n+1)x^{n+1}-((n-1)x^{n-1}+(n-2)x^{n-2}+...2x+1)=0$$
Has exactly one positive root, by Descartes' rule of Signs. Note that $P_n'(0)=1$ and $p_n'(1)=n+1-(n-1+n-2+n-3...)<0$ so the root must lie between 0 and 1.
As a result, the curve intersects the positive x axis in exactly one place.

$$P_n(\phi)=\frac{1}{\phi^n(\phi-1)}(\phi^{2}-\phi-1+\frac{1}{\phi^n})$$
Now, note that $\phi^2-\phi-1=0$ by definition, and $\frac{1}{\phi^n}=(\phi-1)^n$, so
$$P_n(\phi)=\frac{(\phi-1)^{n-1}}{\phi^n}=(\phi-1)^{2n-1}$$
Since, $|\phi-1|<1$, as n tends to infinity, $P_n(\phi)$ tends to zero.

Is this sufficient?

Comment: That doesn't show the uniqueness, though. Not sure about existence, but that's not hard to show anyhow.

Comment: For uniqueness, look at the roots of $(x-1)x^{n+1}-x^n+1$, and use Rolle's theorem. Also, since $P_n(1)=-(n-1)<0$ and $\lim_{x\to +\infty}P_n(x)=+\infty$, we get that $x_n>1$.

Comment: For the limit, you should add more details (in the equation it's $x_n$, not $x$).

Comment: Some simple key facts to show uniqueness: (1) $\lim_{n\to\infty} x^n = 0$ for $|x|<1$, (2) $x=1$ is not a solution of the original equation, (3) $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1/x^n = 0$ for $|x|>1$.

Comment: @Davide Giraudo: if you're willing then you may post your own solution with the way you described above.

Comment: @DanLitt: thanks for your solution.

Comment: As Davide pointed out, this solution is very incomplete in that it just assumes there is a limit $>1$. First, there might not be a limit at all, second, even if there is a limit, we might have $x_n\to 1$ and therefore $-1/x_n^n$ could converge to a non-zero limit, so the equation on $x$ would become different.

Comment: I've had a go at making the answer more complete - let me know if it's sufficient.

Answer (score 6):

Descartes' rule of signs shows that $P_n$ has at most one positive root, and since $P_n(1)=1-n<0$ and $\lim_{+\infty} P_n=+\infty$, $P_n$ has exactly one positive root $x_n>1$.
Let
$$R_n(x)=x^{-n}(x-1)P_n(x)=x^2-x-1+x^{-n}$$
Then $R_n$ has exactly two positive roots 1 and $x_n$, so that it is negative on the interval $(1,x_n)$ and positive on $(x_n,+\infty)$: for all $x>1$,
$$\operatorname{sgn} (x-x_n)=\operatorname{sgn} R_n(x)$$

For all $x>1$, $R_n(x)$ converges pointwise to $$Q(x)=x^2-x-1$$

But
$$\operatorname{sgn} Q(x)=\operatorname{sgn} (x-\phi)$$
where $\phi=(1+\sqrt 5)/2$, so that whenever $x\ne\phi$, $\operatorname{sgn} Q(x)\ne 0$ and we have:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \operatorname{sgn} (x-x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \operatorname{sgn} R_n(x)=\operatorname{sgn} Q(x)=\operatorname{sgn} (x-\phi)$$
and therefore $x_n$ converges to $\phi$.

Comment: this is another interesting approch.

Comment: This is a much clearer answer than mine. I don't know why it has less upvotes.